# how to change the source of dijkstras algorithm in python

Tags: python

Here's my python code for finding shortest path using djikstra's algorithm. The source is 0. I want to change the source to 1 and also for 2,3,4. What should I change to get that.
for eg, it is showing output as
0 to 0 is 0
0 to 1 is 4
0 to 2 is 12
0 to 3 is 11
0 to 4 is 19
i want output like
1 to 0 is
1 to 1 is
1 to 2 is
1 to 3 is
1 to 4 is

```
import sys
class Graph():

def __init__(self, vertices):
    self.V = vertices
    self.graph = [[0 for column in range(vertices)]
                for row in range(vertices)]

def printSolution(self, dist):
    print("Vertex \tDistance from Source")
    for node in range(self.V):
        print(node, "\t", dist[node])

def minDistance(self, dist, sptSet):
    min = sys.maxsize
    for u in range(self.V):
        if dist[u] < min and sptSet[u] == False:
            min = dist[u]
            min_index = u

    return min_index
    
def dijkstra(self, src):

    dist = [sys.maxsize] * self.V
    dist[src] = 0
    sptSet = [False] * self.V

    for cout in range(self.V):

        x = self.minDistance(dist, sptSet)
        sptSet[x] = True
        for y in range(self.V):
            if self.graph[x][y] > 0 and sptSet[y] == False and \
                    dist[y] > dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]:
                dist[y] = dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]

    self.printSolution(dist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
g = Graph(5)
g.graph = [
        [0, 4, 0, 5, 0],
        [4, 0, 8, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0, 6, 7],
        [0, 0, 6, 0, 9],
        [0, 0, 7, 9, 0],
        ]

g.dijkstra(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think this is a question you actually have, and that you simply need to think about the code more carefully - because *writing* this code is *much harder* than answering the question. Hint: see where the code says `def dijkstra(self, src):`? What do you suppose `src` might be short for? See where the code says `g.dijkstra(0)`? What do you suppose the `0` means here? When you call the method this way, what do you think will be the value of `src` that is used?

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: have you written this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the source while calling g.dijkstra() method.
This will allow the algorithm to know from where to start from.

```
g.dijkstra(1)
```